# How to make a dynatree from sql query results?

Tags: php, javascript, dynatree

I'm trying to make a dynatree for a selection of overlays for googlemaps. 
screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUrJK.png

Now I'm having trouble making the dynatree's content dynamic. User's should be able to upload these maps and it'd be available to be selected in the tree.

In the screenshot, the tree is working perfectly but its content is static because i declared it in the .js file. Turning the php sql array into the "tree" array is what's puzzling me. Any ideas?

Comment: I think i found the answer. I found [json_encode($row )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create the JSON data or and JS array from your query result, and you can use the ajax or the children option to set it to the tree depending on your needs.